# Add image to DB from Telerik upload control

Tags: telerik-mvc

I am using MVC3 with telerik controls 
I have a situation where I need to add image to DB on click of register/update button in my screen.
I am using the following code to do so.

```
<fieldset class="fieldsetattachment">
<legend>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)</legend>
<div class="editor-field">
@(Html.Telerik().Upload()
.Name("attachments")
.Multiple(false)
.Async(async => async
.AutoUpload(false)
.Save("Create","Employee")    
)
)
</div>
```

The issue is that I need to start the upload process when the create button on the screen is pressed and not when the upload button on the telerik upload is pressed.
Also I want to hide the upload button from telerik.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y0,

Since there is not API which allow you to call the submit file with JavaScript you can hide the button like this on document ready:

```
$('.t-upload-selected').hide();
```

And when your custom button is clicked to submit your form you need to trigger the click programatically.

```
$('.t-upload-selected').click();
```

Of course if you have several upload widgets on the page you will need to be more concrete with the selectors.